# How do references resolve the ambiguity in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, reference, multiple-inheritance

The following code shows the notorious diamond inheritance. But it seems that an appropriate reference designation avoids the ambiguity.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdio.h>

class B {
public:
  int m_a ;
} ;

class D1 : public B { } ;

class D2 : public B { } ;

class E : public D1, public D2 { } ;

  int main () {
  E e ;
  D1& c = e ;
  D2& d = e ; 

  e.D1::m_a = 2 ;
  e.D2::m_a = 2 ;

  std::cout << c.m_a << std::endl ;
  std::cout << d.m_a << std::endl ;

  c.m_a = 3 ;
  std::cout << c.m_a << std::endl ;
  std::cout << d.m_a << std::endl ;

  printf ( "%p\n", &c ) ;
  printf ( "%p\n", &d ) ;
  printf ( "%p\n", &e ) ;
  printf ( "\n" ) ;
  printf ("%p\n", (void*) &(c.m_a)) ;
  printf ("%p\n", (void*) &(d.m_a)) ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

The output is:

```
 2
 2
 3
 2
 0xffffcbf0
 0xffffcbf4
 0xffffcbf0

 0xffffcbf0
 0xffffcbf4
```

So it seems that a reference 'knows' where it should start in the memory layout of the object 'e' which contains duplicated D1::m_a and D2::m_a . I wonder how it is achieved in C++ implementation. Thanks!

Comment: There's no diamond in your hierarchy... And note that there's nothing conceptually hard here at all. It's merely a question of how to say what you mean when there are local ambiguities *in naming*. As far as implementation is concerned, this is no different from if `D1` and `D2` had different bases.

Comment: Are you talking about this part? `E e ;  D1& c = e ;  D2& d = e ;`

Comment: It would be a diamond if they used the same B. To do that, you'd have to use virtual inheritance. Right now you just have two objects in E, a D1 and a D2, both with their own B.

Comment: note that you can use `cout` to output the addresses, you don't need to revert to printf

Comment: voted to close as unclear -- it's not clear to me from this question what part of the code you have trouble with or why you feel there's an ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to discover what's happening is by printing `(void*)(&c)` and `(void*)(&d)`. The two references refer to distinct subobjects of `e`.

Also, the references to `D1` and `D2` do **not** know they're inside some `E`. A reference can refer to any object in memory, but it doesn't know about the surroundings of that object.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking. And as far as I understand now: the program always directs the 'pointer' to the position according to the Base classes during the declaration ` D2& d = e` or `D1& c = e`. I don't know if I understand correctly.

Comment: Well, the declaration is a reference declaration, and not a pointer, but otherwise it's correct. (You can get a pointer from a reference by applying the `&` address-of operator)